# Cucumber Guice / Injector seems not to be thread-safe (Parallel execution / ExecutorService)

Tags: thread-safety, cucumber, testng, guice, executorservice

[long description warning]

I'm running some cucumber tests which have to be executed intercalated a defined server - for instance:
a.feature -> JBoss Server 1 | b.feature -> JBoss Serv. 2 | c.feature -> JB1 | etc.

For that, I created a hypothetical ExecutorService like this:

```
    final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2); //numberOfServers

    for (Runnable task : tasks) {
        executorService.execute(task);
    }
    executorService.shutdown();
    try {
        executorService.awaitTermination(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        //doX();
    }
```

The way that I manage about how will be the server chosen as liable to execute is:

inside of my Runnable class created for the executorService, I pass as a parameter a **instanceId** to a TestNG (XmlTest class) as below:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    setupTest().run();
}

private TestNG setupTest() {
    TestNG testNG = new TestNG();
    XmlSuite xmlSuite = new XmlSuite();
    XmlTest xmlTest = new XmlTest(xmlSuite);
    xmlTest.setName(//irrelevant);
    xmlTest.addParameter("instanceId", String.valueOf(instanceId));
    xmlTest.setXmlClasses(..........);
    testNG.setXmlSuites(..........);
    return testNG;
}
```

Then, I get this just fine in a class that ***extends TestNgCucumberAdaptor***:

```
@BeforeTest
@Parameters({"instanceId"})
public void setInstanceId(@Optional("") String instanceId) {
    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(instanceId)) {
        this.instanceId = Integer.valueOf(instanceId);
    }
}
```

And inside a @BeforeClass I'm populating a Pojo with this instanceId and setting the Pojo in a threadLocal attribute of another class. So far, so good.

```
public class CurrentPojoContext {
    private static final ThreadLocal<PojoContext> TEST_CONTEXT = new ThreadLocal<PojoContext>();
    ...
    public static PojoContext getContext(){
        TEST_CONTEXT.get();
    }
```

Now the problem really starts - I'm using Guice (Cucumber guice as well) in a 3rd class, injecting this pojo object that contains the instanceId. The example follows:

```
public class Environment {    
    protected final PojoContext pojoContext;    
    @Inject
    public Environment() {
        this.pojoContext = CurrentPojoContext.getContext();
    }    
    public void foo() {
        print(pojoContext.instanceId); // output: 1
        Another.doSomething(pojoContext);
    }

    class Another{
        public String doSomething(PojoContext p){
            print(p.instanceId); // output: 2
        }
    }
}
```

Here it is not every time like this the outputs (1 and 2) but from time to time, I realized that the execution of different threads is messing with the attribute pojoContext. I know that is a little confusing, but my guess is that the Guice Injector is not thread-safe for this scenario - it might be a long shot, but I'd appreciate if someone else takes a guess.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, just in order to provide a solution for someone else, my solution was the following:

1. Create a class that maintains a Map with an identifier (unique and thread-safe one) as the key and a Guice Injector as value;
2. Inside my instantiation of Guice injector, I created my own module

   ```
   Guice.createInjector(Stage.PRODUCTION, MyOwnModules.SCENARIO, new RandomModule());
   ```

   and for this module:

   ```
   public class MyOwnModules {
       public static final Module SCENARIO = new ScenarioModule(MyOwnCucumberScopes.SCENARIO);
   }
   ```

   the scope defined here provides the following:

   ```
   public class MyOwnCucumberScopes {
       public static final ScenarioScope SCENARIO = new ParallelScenarioScope();
   }
   ```
3. To sum up, the thread-safe will be in the ParallelScenarioScope:

   ```
   public class ParallelScenarioScope implements ScenarioScope {

       private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ParallelScenarioScope.class);

       private final ThreadLocal<Map<Key<?>, Object>> threadLocalMap = new ThreadLocal<Map<Key<?>, Object>>();

       @Override
       public <T> Provider<T> scope(final Key<T> key, final Provider<T> unscoped) {
           return new Provider<T>() {
               public T get() {
                   Map<Key<?>, Object> scopedObjects = getScopedObjectMap(key);

                   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                   T current = (T) scopedObjects.get(key);
                   if (current == null && !scopedObjects.containsKey(key)) {
                       current = unscoped.get();
                       scopedObjects.put(key, current);
                   }
                   return current;
               }
           };
       }

       protected <T> Map<Key<?>, Object> getScopedObjectMap(Key<T> key) {
           Map<Key<?>, Object> map = threadLocalMap.get();
           if (map == null) {
               throw new OutOfScopeException("Cannot access " + key + " outside of a scoping block");
           }
           return map;
       }

       @Override
       public void enterScope() {
           checkState(threadLocalMap.get() == null, "A scoping block is already in progress");
           threadLocalMap.set(new ConcurrentHashMap<Key<?>, Object>());
       }

       @Override
       public void exitScope() {
           checkState(threadLocalMap.get() != null, "No scoping block in progress");
           threadLocalMap.remove();
       }

       private void checkState(boolean expression, String errorMessage) {
           if (!expression) {
               LOGGER.info("M=checkState, Will throw exception: " + errorMessage);
               throw new IllegalStateException(errorMessage);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Now the gotcha is just to be careful regarding the @ScenarioScoped and the code will work as expected.